# window.print() IE 8 crash

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-8, crash

IE8 crashes all the time when button onclick is invoked with window.print()

Is there any alternatives to window.print() function ?
browser crash after javascript error

An error has occurred in the script on this page
line: 1536
Char: 1
Error: Invalid procedure call or argument
Code: 0
URL: res://ieframe.dll/preview.js

Comment: Does it work on any other page or is this just a bug in your browser. Should work fine.

Comment: No it does not work on any page in IE8.

Comment: Do you have some sort of third party pop up blocker installed or some other add-ons? Try disabling them and see if it goes away.

Comment: No .. there is no addons installed. is it possible to caputure IE script error in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be specific to your computer (I tried on my own and didn't see any issues).

Some other people are facing this problem, I found for you a tutorial of how this problem could be fixed (in french only, no translation available in english but you might use google translate)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2654204/fr

I also found a thread about this problem it might help you :

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/resieframedllpreviewjs-script-error-when-i-try-to/c1e623d6-d6e4-4eaa-9e27-53d8cf2aad25